Handling realtime socket events whilst initially fetching query
I fetch chats initially, using useQuery, and then any subsequent updates to chats such as new chats are handled by my realtime socket handlers.
ChatList.js:
const { data, error, isFetching, isLoading } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["chats"],
    queryFn: fetchChats,
    staleTime: Infinity,
})

In my SocketContext.js, whenever I receieve a new chat, I add it to the cache. If the query is initially fetching for the first time, the cache is obviously empty at this point. I check whether this existing chat is already in the cache, and if not I add it to the cache.
socket.on("new_chat", (data) => {
     const {chatData} = data
     queryClient.setQueryData(["chats"], (prevChats = []) => {
            const existingChat = prevChats?.find((c) => c._id === chatData._id)
            // Add to cache if not already there
            if (!existingChat) return [chatData, ...prevChats]

            const filteredChats = prevChats.filter((c) => c._id !== existingChat._id)
            const updatedChat = { ...existingChat, latestMessage: message }

            return [updatedChat, ...filteredChats]
      }) })

The problem I have is that if a chat is added to the cache whilst initially fetching, it is then overwritten when useQuery finishes fetching. This data from useQuery may not include this new chat. I tried to call invalidateQueries given I receieve a chat in realtime and isFetching for the chats is true, however this is pointless as the cache is empty at this point so invalidateQueries does nothing.
One solution I tried was storing realtime updates in a queue whilst isFetching is true for the chats query and then merge the updates once fetching completes, however this seems tedious especially considering onSuccess was removed from the useQuery hook. Any ways I could potentially handle this?

You need to do Queue Realtime Updates
Store new chats in a queue while fetching:
const newChatsQueue = useRef([]);

socket.on("new_chat", (data) => {
    const { chatData } = data;
    if (isFetching) {
        newChatsQueue.current.push(chatData);
    } else {
        updateChats(chatData);
    }
});

const updateChats = (chatData) => {
    queryClient.setQueryData(["chats"], (prevChats = []) => {
        const exists = prevChats.some((c) => c._id === chatData._id);
        if (!exists) return [chatData, ...prevChats];
        return prevChats;
    });
};

Apply the queue after fetching completes:
useEffect(() => {
    if (!isFetching && newChatsQueue.current.length) {
        queryClient.setQueryData(["chats"], (prevChats = []) => [
            ...newChatsQueue.current,
            ...prevChats,
        ]);
        newChatsQueue.current = [];
    }
}, [isFetching]);

This avoids overwriting realtime updates during the initial fetch.

I tried implementing this solution. The problem is once the initial fetch completes, isFetching is false so I display the chats. The useffect  then updates the chats to apply the queue, which means suddenly we have 10 chats appended. given there were 10 chats in the queue. I was hoping for a solution perhaps more native to react-query maybe using a method they provide I.e like invalidateQueries which I previously tried.
